# position of "with the benefit of hindsight"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

What's the difference between the following sentences? Do the different positions of the boldfaced phrase make any difference in meaning?

> He admitted that, **with the benefit of hindsight**, the original launch had not been large enough.

> He admitted, **with the benefit of hindsight**, that the original launch had not been large enough.

Comment: My take on it is that the second version means that **his own** change of opinion was based on hindsight, while the first could refer to the general opinion of those responsible for 'the launch'.

Answer (score 2):

This is an embedded clause structure. [He admitted [that.....]].

The first sentence [He admitted [that, with the benefit of hindsight, the original....]], the prepositional phrase modifies the embedded clause.  I think the meaning is strange here: the original launch had not been large enough with the benefit of hindsight.

The second sentence [He admitted, with the benefit of hindsight, [that ....]] makes more sense. The prepositional phrase modifies the finite verb "admitted".

Comment: Thank you. Are you a native speaker of Chinese or Cantonese?

Comment: Yeah.  You can tell from my writing?